# For large datasets are JOINS better than using JSONB or vice versa, in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, join, jsonb

Here is a simple use case;

I have a posts entity and a tags entity in my app.
There are two types of queries that i want to run here;

1. fetch posts for a tag
2. fetch tags for a post

The two options That I can go with is

1. have separate tables for posts and tags. Then do a join
2. add tags as a jsonb column in my posts table. when trying to fetch posts for a tag (nature), I can do `@> "nature"` and order by post created date.
   When I want to fetch tags for a post, well I dont even need to do anything.

To me JSONB feels much more easier to use and reason with (coming from the JS world).
But I am not able to paint a picture of the performance tradeoff if I were to go for this approach. I understand that JSOB will be much faster when I dont have to filter/search through the objects themselves. 
But what if I have to search for a JSONB attribute in a posts table containing 1M records, each with say 20 or so tags? Will going for joins be a far more performant option in that case?

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for looking into my question. I have read that blog, but I didn't feel like the 3 major points raised against JSONB - baroque queries, no fixed typing and no constraints affect me much. I am used to having my apps enforce the schemas anyway. My major worry is around any perf implications.